# Can AsyncTask be called from a non-UI worker thread?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

Is it possible to call a AsyncTask from a non-UI thread? AsyncTask's postExecute() gets executed on Main/UI thread to update the response from doInBackground(). Wondering if I can use AsyncTask from a worker thread to fetch network data?

Comment: When you have a question like this, read [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: If you're in a worker thread aren't you already using AsyncTask??

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Under: Threading rules. Your answer is right there.

I almost don't want to give you the link, because it only shows you didn't even bother looking.

Answer (score 0):

According to here you must call execute on the main UI thread:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html